# Reverse scoring survey scores

Tags: r

I am using survey data from the World Values Survey. Some of my variables are scored such that
1=Always Justifiable
10=Never justifiable

I want to reverse score these variables so that the Never Justifiable observations = 1 and the Always Justifiable observations = 10

I can't seem to find any simple code that will help me, almost everyone has got a different way of doing it. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you share what you already tried and what you don't like or prefer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the column of dataframe `df` is called `x`, you can simply write

```
df$x_recoded = 11-df$x
```

This is because your recoding is so simple. If it gets more complicated, you might need something like `dplyr::recode()` or `dplyr::mutate()`.

Comment: Happy to hear that! If the answer resolved your question, please consider marking it as accepted with the gray check to its left.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```r
library(dplyr,warn.conflicts = F)

df <- tibble(x = c(7,3,10))

df %>% 
  mutate(xrev = 10-x)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>       x  xrev
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     7     3
#> 2     3     7
#> 3    10     0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Since his scale starts at 1 and not at 0, you need `xrev = 11-x`.

Comment: Thank you for this code! It will be handy for me going forward!